# React Js Upload Images using Api

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, antd

So I am trying to upload a file using React Js ant design upload component now the issue I am facing is that whenever I try to submit an image I received the following error:

Access to fetch at 'https://freeimage.host/api/1/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have attached the code that I have written to upload and handle file submissions.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Regarding the CORS error itself, a quick search will find *so many duplicate questions*.  Essentially the server would need to be configured to allow cross-origin AJAX requests from your domain (localhost).  If it's a 3rd party system then this is unlikely to happen.  You'd either need to not use AJAX or would need to proxy the requests through your own server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding headers to the fetch inside your handleSubmission arrow function and stringify the body.

```
fetch('https://freeimage.host/api/1/upload', {
  key: apiKey,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(formData),
})
```

Comment: Not working still same error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your backend as node js add following code to it

```
const cors = require("cors");
const corsOpts = {
origin: "*",
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOpts));
```